# Ubicación actual android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps

Estoy desarrollando una app que me muestre mi ubicación actual, he usado `GetLastKnowLocation` pero me muestra la ultima ubicación registrada o null
Necesito obtener los valores de latitud y longitud y guardarlos en dos variables tipo String.
El método que estoy usando es:

```
public  String getLocalizacion(){
    direccionCompleta="";
    URL="http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=15&mrt=loc&t=m&q=";
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        return error  = "SIN PERMISOS";
    }
    else {
        /*Se asigna a la clase LocationManager el servicio a nivel de sistema a partir del nombre.*/
        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        longitudeGPS=loc.getLongitude();
        latitudeGPS=loc.getLatitude();

        //OBTENER DIRECCION
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitudeGPS, longitudeGPS, 1);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                String direccion = DirCalle.getAddressLine(0);
                direccionCompleta = "Estoy en "+URL+ latitudeGPS + "+" + longitudeGPS;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return direccionCompleta;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener la posición real actual puedes utilizar `requestLocationUpdates()`. Este método necesita de cuatro parámetros `requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, listener)`.

**¿Como usarlo?**

Para usar este método hay que seguir los siguientes pasos.

1- Crear el location manager (como ya lo haces):

```
locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

2.- Iniciar el método del location manager (cambiar `minTime` y `minDistance` a tu gusto):

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, locationListenerGPS);
```

3.- Crear el listener con sus funciones:

```
LocationListener locationListenerGPS=new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
        double lat=location.getLatitude();
        double lon=location.getLongitude();    
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};
```

Como ves cada vez que se cumplan las condiciones del `minTime` y `minDistance` se ejecutará la función de `onLocationChanged()` y ahí podrás coger la posición actual.

Por último me queda añadir que si sólo necesitas coger la localización una vez, tendrás que parar el listener. Para ello, después de coger la latitud y longitud por primera vez, tendrás que añadir este código en el `onLocationChanged()`:

```
locManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGPS);
```

Esta no es la única manera de conseguirlo ni de programarlo, pero te puede orientar para que consigas lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente te recomiendo agregar los dos permisos y requerirlos manualmente para dispositivos Android 6.0+

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Te recomiendo usar [Fused Location Provider](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Inicializa [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)  en `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`:

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
  ...
  ...
  ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ...
   ...
   fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
   ...
}
```

ahora **puedes usar el método [getLastLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#getLastLocation())
 para obtener la mejor ubicación más reciente actualmente disponible.**

```
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {            
                if (location != null) {
                    //Obtiene geolocalización
                }
            }
        });
```